# Invalid use of group function (with no conditions)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, sequelpro

The table looks like this:

```
| colA | colB | colC | colD |some other cols
-----------------------------
|double|double| int  | int  |some other datatyps
```

I want to select the sum of each column and group by them. At the moment I have no conditions wich musst be true. So this is my query:

```
SELECT SUM(colA) as 'cola', SUM(colB)as 'colb', SUM(colC) as 'colc', SUM(colD) as 'cold', SUM(colA - colB)as 'sub'
FROM table_name
GROUP BY cola,colb,colc,cold,sub
```

And then it creates the error : Invalid use of group function

I red several posts about this error, but they all had an WHERE condition and a HAVING solved this problem, but I dont have a condition. Any Ideas what could cause this error message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `GROUP BY` clause at all :

```
SELECT SUM(t.colA) as 'cola',
       SUM(t.colB)as 'colb',
       SUM(t.colC) as 'colc',
       SUM(t.colD) as 'cold',
       SUM(t.colA - t.colB)as 'sub'
FROM table_name t
```

A `GROUP BY` clause is used to get calculated / aggregated / distinct value per `GROUP` , like an `ID` , since you want the total sum, there's no need for a `group by` clause

```
GROUP BY cola,colb,colc,cold,sub
```

This row means that each group is the combination of `cola,colb,colc,cold,sub` , which doesn't exists yet since `sub` is a calculated column! Don't include it in your group by

If you want to distinct duplicates, then either use `DISTINCT` , or drop the `sub` column from the group by :

```
GROUP BY t.cola,t.colb,t.colc,t.cold
```

Comment: Maybe at the moment but later I have an condition and then I need need to group

Comment: Group by what?  @Isabell

Comment: @Isabell then post that other query

Comment: For what? To get distinct values? What's the purpose ?

Comment: Can't group on 'cola'

Answer (score 0):

Your fault is that in the group by you include the sub that doesn't exist in the table.

So try this:

```
SELECT SUM(colA) as 'cola', SUM(colB)as 'colb', 
SUM(colC) as 'colc', SUM(colD) as 'cold', SUM(colA - colB)as 'sub'
FROM table_name
GROUP BY cola,colb,colc,cold
```

Comment: Can't group on 'cola'

Comment: What DB you use?

In simple SQL i used that simple code and works perfectly for me:

    create table ca (colA float,colB float,colC int,colD int)


SELECT SUM(colA) as 'cola', SUM(colB)as 'colb', 

    SUM(colC) as 'colc', SUM(colD) as 'cold', SUM(colA - colB)as 'sub'

    FROM ca

    GROUP BY cola,colb,colc,cold

Comment: Aurora and use it via sequel pro